# Matrix Derivative Product Rule $\frac{d}{dx} \langle x,y\rangle Ax $

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$,$x,y\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$. What is the derivative of the following expression?

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \langle x,y\rangle Ax 
$$

**What I tried:**

Applying the product rule doesn't work because the first term (see next equation) is inconsistent dimensionally, or I am applying it in the wrong way. Let $f(x) = \langle x,y \rangle, g(x) = Ax$, then

$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x)g(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx} g(x) +  f(x)\frac{dg(x)}{dx} = xAx + \langle x,y \rangle A$$.

Here the first term in the last equation doesn't make sense dimensionally, any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding coordinates one may alternatively compute $d_pf(v)$, where $f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle Ax$.  For that purpose take a differential path $c$, defined on an interval containing $0$, satisfying $c(0)=p$ and $\dot c(0)=v$, where $\dot c(t)$ is a shorthand for $\frac{d}{dt}c(t)$.  Now compute
$$\begin{align}
d_pf(v)&=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}f(c(t))\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}\bigl(\langle c(t),y)\rangle Ac(t)\bigr)\\
&=\bigl(\langle \dot c(t),y\rangle A\cdot c(t)+\langle c(t),y\rangle A\cdot\dot c(t)\bigr)\big|_{t=0}\\
&=\langle v,y\rangle Ap+\langle p,y\rangle Av.
\end{align}$$

*Edit*: If you insist to write the differential without argument (but should one?), proceed as follows:
$$\begin{align}
d_pf(v)&=\langle v,y\rangle Ap+\langle p,y\rangle Av\\
&=A\bigl(\langle v,y\rangle p+\langle p,y\rangle v  \bigr).
\end{align}$$
Observe that
$$\langle v,y\rangle p=
p\langle y,v\rangle=py^Tv,
$$
hence
$$\begin{align}
d_pf(v)&=A\bigl(py^Tv+\langle p,y\rangle v  \bigr)\\
&=A\bigl(py^T+\langle p,y\rangle I\bigr)v
\end{align}
$$
and finally
$$d_pf=A\bigl(py^T+\langle p,y\rangle I \bigr)$$

But, to be honest, I like the expression $d_pf(v)$ more for symmetry reasons.  And it works for any inner product.

Comment: Still your answer is different from the one @J.P. provides. Which one is correct?

Comment: So what does this make $\frac{d}{dx}(\langle x,\,y\rangle Ax)$, in which only $A,\,x,\,y$ should appear?

Comment: It's just the differential evaluated at $v$.  For clarity I've replaced $x$ by $p$.  Undoing that wo have $$d_xf(v)=A(\langle v,y\rangle x+\langle x,y\rangle v)=A(xy^Tv+\langle x,y\rangle v),$$ hence we have $$d_xf=A(xy^T+\langle x,y\rangle I).$$

Answer (score 2):

In [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and the standard basis for which $\langle x,\,y\rangle=x_ky_k$, you're differentiating a vector of $i$th component $x_ky_kA_{il}x_l$ with respect to a vector of $j$th component $x_j$, giving a matrix of $ij$ entry$$\delta_{jk}y_kA_{il}x_l+x_ky_kA_{il}\delta_{jl}=y_jA_{il}x_l+x_ky_kA_{ij}=(Axy^T+\langle x,\,y\rangle A)_{ij}.$$In other words, the derivative is $A(xy^T+\langle x,\,y\rangle I_n)$, with $I_n$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Define the vector-valued function
$$\eqalign{
f &= (y^Tx)(Ax) \\
}$$
and calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= (Ax)(y^Tdx) + (y^Tx)(A\,dx) \\
   &= \Big(Axy^T + (y^Tx)A\Big)\,dx \\
   &= A\Big(xy^T + (y^Tx)I\Big)\,dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= A\Big(xy^T + (y^Tx)I\Big) \\
}$$
which is another way to derive JG's result while avoiding index notation.

Your error was to **assume** that the product rule is valid for the gradient of a vector-valued function like $f$, but it isn't.

The problem is that a gradient operation changes the tensorial character of any term to which it is applied (i.e. it turns vectors into matrices), and matrix multiplication is inherently non-commutative. Index notation was developed to handle *precisely* such calculations, but with standard matrix notation you must proceed very cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle Ax.
$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)(u)&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+tu)-f(x)}{t}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\langle x+tu,y\rangle A(x+tu)-\langle x,y\rangle Ax}{t}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\left(\langle u,y\rangle Ax+\langle x,y\rangle Au+t\langle u,y\rangle Au\right)\\
&=&\langle u,y\rangle Ax+\langle x,y\rangle Au.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So what does this make $\frac{d}{dx}(\langle x,\,y\rangle Ax)$, in which only $A,\,x,\,y$ should appear?

Comment: Let me think about.

Comment: Nothing to think about: you just evaluated the differential at $u$.  See the edit to my answer.